# List.Add(x). Is x a REFERENCE or a VALUE?

Tags: c#

Regarding this data and (pseudo) code:

```
List<myClass> Periods = new List<myClass>();

// contents of Periods is:
Periods[0] = "000";
Periods[1] = "111";
Periods[2] = "222";
Periods[3] = "REST"; // REST PERIOD
Periods[4] = "444";
Periods[5] = "REST"; // REST PERIOD
Periods[6] = "666";
Periods[7] = "777";
Periods[8] = "888";
```

The following code iterates through the list, and pulls out multiple list elements as they occur between REST periods into individual lists, and adds these lists to a "list of lists".  There may be one or more List Entries between rest periods.

```
List<List<Period>> DutyDayPeriods = new List<List<Period>>();
List<Period> thisList = new List<Period>();

for (int i = 0; i < Periods.Count; i++ ) {    
    thisList.Add(Periods[i]);

    if (Periods[i].Rest == "REST") {   
        DutyDayPeriods.Add(thisList);
        thisList.Clear();   
    }    
}
```

At the bottom of the for loop, DutyDayPeriods<> contains 1-n identical copies of "thisList".  Essentially the last set of list items between the last rest period and the end of the list:

So, I am expecting the following:

```
DutyDayPeriods[0]
    Period 000
    Period 111
    Period 222
DutyDayPeriods[1]
    Period 444
DutyDayPeriods[2]
    Period 666
    Period 777
    Period 888
```

But I'm actually getting:

```
DutyDayPeriods[0]
    Period 666
    Period 777
    Period 888
DutyDayPeriods[1]
    Period 666
    Period 777
    Period 888
DutyDayPeriods[2]
    Period 666
    Period 777
    Period 888
```

`thisList` is behaving like a **reference**, not a **value**.

Every time `thisList` changes, it seems to change retroactively to items that have already been added to `DutyDayPeriods`.

Is this the case?  And if so, how do I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I modified the following to prevent the rest periods themselves from being included.  Just in case one of you notices that.  ;-)

```
if (Periods[i].Rest != "REST") {
    thisList.Add(Periods[i]);
}
else {
    DutyDayFlights.Add(thisList);
    thisList = new List<Period>();  
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to read up on _Value Types_ and _Reference Types_ in any C# reference (book, web page, tutorial, etc.).  That distinction is very important in C# and other .NET languages.  In C#, any type you create as a _class_ is a reference type and anything else (generally, a type that is a_struct_, but also things like Enums) are value types.  Not surprisingly, variables that refer to reference type objects refer to them by reference.  Value type variables contain values.

Comment: Re the edit: also pay attention to what happens to the last block of items.

Comment: Yes, I did have to handle that last block differently.  Good catch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a `List<T>` is always a reference.

You just need to replace `.Clear()` with creating a new list.

```
DutyDayPeriods.Add(thisList);
//thisList.Clear();   
thisList = new List<Period>();
```

Comment: So, creating a new list destroys the old one, and thus breaks any reference to it?  That makes sense.

Comment: Nothing here is being destroyed, not even garbage collected. When your end result is a list-of-lists you need to keep them all to fill it up.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, you're working with references. The longer answer is more complicated. C# handles simple types (`int` and `char` for example) and structs by value but class objects are always handled by reference. So, when you call `thisList.Add` with a `Period` object, you're actually sending a reference to that object. If what you actually want is the value, you should do something like this:

```
DutyDayPeriods.Add(thisList);
thisList = new List<Period>();
```

This will dereference everything on `thisList` from `thisList`, meaning that the only remaining "active" references will be on your other collection.

Comment: No, nothing of or in thisList will be eligable for GC after this code.

Comment: "but more complex objects are always handled by reference." this is misleading; you can have some *very* complex value-types - much more complex than many classes; the interesting question becomes: is "objects" the escape clause here? the point is : there is a category that is neither primitives nor classes;

Comment: @MarcGravell Forgive me, but I'm going to need an example of this. To be fair, my C# experience is only about 4 years but I have yet to see anything that was not primitive which wasn't passed by reference, although I suppose structs would be the exception to that rule

Comment: @HenkHolterman When you set `thisList` to `new List<Period>`, I assume that the original references contained in `thisList` have to go somewhere. Maybe the get put on the heap for GC later. In that case, it is a matter of semantics and I'll update my response to reflect that.

Comment: No, you still miss the point. The reference _in_ thisList is added to DutyDayPeriods just before it is overwritten by a new one. There is nothing to do for the GC here, everything remains reachable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Are you sure? All the objects do yes, but the individual pointers on `thisList` had to be deleted when it was newed-up again. Those have to be handled (returned to memory) somehow

Comment: Yes I am sure and no, nothing needs to be deleted here. Think about how a `List<List< >>` looks in memory, draw it on paper. `thisList` is not a List, it is a reference to a List.

Comment: @Woody1193 heck, a *string* isn't "passed by reference" by default - nor is `class MyType`. There's a **huge** difference between "passed by reference" and "a reference, passed by value". You seem to be talking about the latter. The nomenclature **really, really matters here** - you kinda need to be precise. A list, etc: is almost always a "reference passed by value"; a custom struct is sometimes a "value passed by value", and sometimes a "value passed by reference" (just calling `someValueType.SomeMethod()` is "value passed by reference", for example)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: @Woody1193 so then it all comes down to "is it a class? Or a struct?" A class is always exposed *as* a reference, whether or not that reference is passed by value or by reference; a struct is *usually* a value (whether or not that value is passed by value or by reference). Both classes and structs can be simple or complex - it isn't about complexity. The "usually" there leaves some wriggle room for boxing, interfaces, interior managed pointers, constrained calls, and a few other subtleties.